# Error when using the command "from polyglot.detect import Detector"

Tags: python, polyglot

I was playing with the polyglot function to convert the text from one language to another like Spanish to English.

I was following the instructions to install the Polyglot and the required modules.

But while running the code

```py
from polyglot.detect import Detector
```

I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    from polyglot.detect import Detector   
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\polyglot-15.5.2-py3.4.egg\polyglot\detect\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .base import Detector, Language   
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\polyglot-15.5.2-py3.4.egg\polyglot\detect\base.py", line 11, in <module>
    from icu import Locale ImportError: No module named 'icu'
```

I'm not sure what I need to be doing.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/47106810/3323084

Answer (score 16):

You need to install the libraries polyglot, PyICU and pycld2 with the commands:

```
pip install polyglot
pip install PyICU
pip install pycld2
```

Comment: Another package that should be installed is `pip install morfessor`

Answer (score 8):

You need to install https://github.com/ovalhub/pyicu

```
pip install pyicu
```