# How to determine the language of a piece of text?

Tags: python, nlp

I want to get this:

```
Input text: "ру́сский язы́к"
Output text: "Russian" 

Input text: "中文"
Output text: "Chinese" 

Input text: "にほんご"
Output text: "Japanese" 

Input text: "العَرَبِيَّة"
Output text: "Arabic"
```

How can I do it in python?

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545977/python-can-i-detect-unicode-string-language-code

Comment: Nicely summarized here https://stackoverflow.com/a/48436520/2063605

Comment: Maybe see also https://github.com/topics/language-identification?l=python

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Have you had a look at [langdetect](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/langdetect?)?

```
from langdetect import detect

lang = detect("Ein, zwei, drei, vier")

print lang
#output: de
```

Comment: Not very accurate - detects language of text 'anatomical structure' as `ro`(Romanian). Multiple language output required for such cases. polyglot performs much better.

Comment: Interesting, for the same example `langdetect` can determine different languages :-)

Comment: for some reason, langdetect is given errors, I am using Python 3.6

Comment: @DenisKuzin I am getting romanian only for "anatomical structure". Wonder if you can share the langdetect version you are using?

Comment: Is not accurate, detects "god is love" as hr that is Croatian

Comment: `langdetect` is actually broken if operated in a loop and you don't reset the text buffer between loops. https://github.com/Mimino666/langdetect/issues/77

Answer (score 381):

## 1. [TextBlob](https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/api_reference.html#textblob.blob.BaseBlob.detect_language). (Deprecated - Use official Google Translate API instead)

Requires NLTK package, uses Google.

```
from textblob import TextBlob
b = TextBlob("bonjour")
b.detect_language()
```

`pip install textblob`

Note: This solution requires internet access and Textblob is using [Google Translate's language detector by calling the API](https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob/blob/e733d597db9908f192c5f5cb472523ad4de7d6b9/textblob/translate.py).

## 2. [Polyglot](https://polyglot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Installation.html).

Requires numpy and some arcane libraries, <s>unlikely to get it work for Windows</s>. (For Windows, get an appropriate versions of **PyICU**, **Morfessor** and **PyCLD2** from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/), then just `pip install downloaded_wheel.whl`.) Able to detect texts with mixed languages.

```
from polyglot.detect import Detector

mixed_text = u"""
China (simplified Chinese: 中国; traditional Chinese: 中國),
officially the People's Republic of China (PRC), is a sovereign state
located in East Asia.
"""
for language in Detector(mixed_text).languages:
        print(language)

# name: English     code: en       confidence:  87.0 read bytes:  1154
# name: Chinese     code: zh_Hant  confidence:   5.0 read bytes:  1755
# name: un          code: un       confidence:   0.0 read bytes:     0
```

`pip install polyglot`

To install the dependencies, run:
`sudo apt-get install python-numpy libicu-dev`

Note: Polyglot is using `pycld2`, see https://github.com/aboSamoor/polyglot/blob/master/polyglot/detect/base.py#L72 for details.

## 3. [chardet](https://chardet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html)

Chardet has also a feature of detecting languages if there are character bytes in range (127-255]:

```
>>> chardet.detect("Я люблю вкусные пампушки".encode('cp1251'))
{'encoding': 'windows-1251', 'confidence': 0.9637267119204621, 'language': 'Russian'}
```

`pip install chardet`

## 4. [langdetect](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/langdetect?)

Requires large portions of text. It uses non-deterministic approach under the hood. That means you get different results for the same text sample. Docs say you have to use following code to make it determined:

```
from langdetect import detect, DetectorFactory
DetectorFactory.seed = 0
detect('今一はお前さん')
```

`pip install langdetect`

## 5. [guess_language](https://bitbucket.org/spirit/guess_language)

Can detect very short samples by using [this](https://pythonhosted.org/pyenchant/) spell checker with dictionaries.

`pip install guess_language-spirit`

## 6. [langid](https://github.com/saffsd/langid.py)

langid.py provides both a module

```
import langid
langid.classify("This is a test")
# ('en', -54.41310358047485)
```

and a command-line tool:

```
$ langid < README.md
```

`pip install langid`

## 7. [FastText](https://fasttext.cc)

FastText is a text classifier, can be used to recognize 176 languages with a proper [models for language classification](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/language-identification.html). Download [this model](https://dl.fbaipublicfiles.com/fasttext/supervised-models/lid.176.ftz), then:

```
import fasttext
model = fasttext.load_model('lid.176.ftz')
print(model.predict('الشمس تشرق', k=2))  # top 2 matching languages

(('__label__ar', '__label__fa'), array([0.98124713, 0.01265871]))
```

`pip install fasttext`

## 8. [pyCLD3](https://github.com/bsolomon1124/pycld3)

pycld3 is a neural network model for language identification. This package contains the inference code and a trained model.

```
import cld3
cld3.get_language("影響包含對氣候的變化以及自然資源的枯竭程度")

LanguagePrediction(language='zh', probability=0.999969482421875, is_reliable=True, proportion=1.0)
```

`pip install pycld3`

Comment: `detectlang` is way faster than `Textblob`

Comment: @Anwarvic TextBlob uses Google API (https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob/blob/dev/textblob/translate.py#L33)! that why it's slow.

Comment: `polyglot` ended up being the most performant for my use case. `langid` came in second

Comment: For anyone trying polyglot, apart from the libraries mentioned, I had to install the following libraries to make the import work: through pip - pycld2 & through conda and their dependencies - pyicu, morfessor

Comment: This is a model answer

Comment: You actually don't have to deal with the whole Polyglot package if language detection is the only thing you need. As [stated in the docs](https://polyglot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Detection.html), the detection is done by [pyCLD2](https://github.com/aboSamoor/pycld2), which is very simple and easy to use library.

Comment: There is also [pyCLD3](https://github.com/bsolomon1124/pycld3).

Comment: pyCLD3 is likely the best option of these. Accurate/fast with its word embedding approach while being much easier to use than fasttext, which requires a separate model, doesn't support paragraphs, etc.

Comment: Pretty crazy, TextBlob fails with "HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests"

Comment: I had very good results with pyCLD3 even on short snippets of my strange native tongue.

Comment: Good tip on fasttext. Just tried it and it's pretty good. Seems to preform better on longer passages than shorter ones.

Comment: `guess_language` repository on bitbucket seem to have disappeared. So I made a rewrite of the library at https://github.com/alvations/spirit-guess, hope it helps!

Comment: textBlob need to fix an error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69173608/why-do-i-get-an-http-error-404-when-using-textblob

Comment: fasttest is very heavy, but langdetcet is very light and smart.

Answer (score 38):

@Rabash had a good list of tools on https://stackoverflow.com/a/47106810/610569

And @toto_tico did a nice job in presenting the speed comparison.

Here's a summary to complete the great answers above (as of 2021)

| Language ID software | Used by | Open Source / Model | Rule-based | Stats-based | Can train/tune |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [Google Translate Language Detection](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/basic/detecting-language) | [TextBlob](https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob/blob/e733d597db9908f192c5f5cb472523ad4de7d6b9/textblob/translate.py) (limited usage) | ✕ | - | - | ✕ |
| [Chardet](https://github.com/chardet/chardet) | - | ✓ | ✓ | ✕ | ✕ |
| [Guess Language](https://pypi.org/project/guess-language/) (non-active development) | [spirit-guess](https://github.com/alvations/spirit-guess) (updated rewrite) | ✓ | ✓ | Minimally | ✕ |
| [pyCLD2](https://github.com/aboSamoor/pycld2) | [Polyglot](https://github.com/aboSamoor/polyglot/blob/master/polyglot/detect/base.py#L72) | ✓ | Somewhat | ✓ | Not sure |
| [CLD3](https://github.com/bsolomon1124/pycld3) | - | ✓ | ✕ | ✓ | Possibly |
| [langid-py](https://github.com/saffsd/langid.py) | - | ✓ | Not sure | ✓ | ✓ |
| [langdetect](https://github.com/Mimino666/langdetect) | [SpaCy-langdetect](https://github.com/Abhijit-2592/spacy-langdetect) | ✓ | ✕ | ✓ | ✓ |
| [FastText](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/language-identification.html) | [What The Lang](https://github.com/indix/whatthelang) | ✓ | ✕ | ✓ | Not sure |

Comment: Thank you for your answer, according to your experience which one gives the most accurate/ and fast results for detecting sentences that are written in english?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/fasttext-langdetect/

Comment: https://github.com/adbar/py3langid

Answer (score 35):

If you are looking for ***a library that is fast with long texts***, `polyglot` and `fastext` are doing the best job here.

I sampled 10000 documents from a collection of dirty and random HTMLs, and here are the results:

```
+------------+----------+
| Library    | Time     |
+------------+----------+
| polyglot   | 3.67 s   |
+------------+----------+
| fasttext   | 6.41     |
+------------+----------+
| cld3       | 14 s     |
+------------+----------+
| langid     | 1min 8s  |
+------------+----------+
| langdetect | 2min 53s |
+------------+----------+
| chardet    | 4min 36s |
+------------+----------+
```

---

I have noticed that a lot of the methods focus on short texts, probably because it is the hard problem to solve: if you have a lot of text, it is really easy to detect languages (e.g. one could just use a dictionary!). However, this makes it difficult to find for an easy and suitable method for long texts.

Comment: `polyglot` language detection is based on `pycld2`, that is not that fast all in all. Or is there a way to use it to identify the language in a kind of a batch mode? I have only tried handling sentence by sentence.

Comment: I assume that the long text is in the same language. I read the 10000 documents and keep them in memory. For fastextcc I have to remove the `\n` characters, but not for polyglot (cdl2 results were pretty much the same, I tested it  as well). I don't understand why you think polyglot is slow, It was the fastest. Do you think I should have removed the `\n` as well, and that my results just reflect the first sentence (i.e., before the first `\n`)

Comment: I mean, I check languages of millions of separate documents that are all one line strings. That is slow with pycld2.

Comment: I see, I don't think there is a way to do that. You have to do it one by one. Depending on where your documents are stored you migh be able to use the multiprocessing capabilities. Also, I ended using fasttextcc because I was having some troubles with asian language encodings.

Comment: In my case, most of the documents were long, and a benchmark might look very different with short sentences.

Comment: But what was the success ratio in recognising the language. Parsing the text is one thing, getting the correct outcome another one. If you get 10k document parsed incorrectly in 14s with cld3, I prefer wait 4 mins and use chardet.

Comment: @Andrea, they all should be quite solid options for long texts; as I mentioned the language detection problem is only difficult when the texts are short.  Of course, the quality also depends on your collection,. You will always need to manually tag a random subset of your documents to evaluate the accuracy. I bet most of the "misclassifications" will appear on short texts and/or multi-language texts. Some of this methods will also offer you a confidence/probability value that you can use to cut off noisy texts.

Answer (score 11):

There is an issue with `langdetect` when it is being used for parallelization and it fails. But `spacy_langdetect` is a wrapper for that and you can use it for that purpose. You can use the following snippet as well:

```
import spacy
from spacy_langdetect import LanguageDetector

nlp = spacy.load("en")
nlp.add_pipe(LanguageDetector(), name="language_detector", last=True)
text = "This is English text Er lebt mit seinen Eltern und seiner Schwester in Berlin. Yo me divierto todos los días en el parque. Je m'appelle Angélica Summer, j'ai 12 ans et je suis canadienne."
doc = nlp(text)
# document level language detection. Think of it like average language of document!
print(doc._.language['language'])
# sentence level language detection
for i, sent in enumerate(doc.sents):
    print(sent, sent._.language)
```

Comment: I followed your answer, but I think I am still getting the same speed as with the `langdetect`. I have a DF column with texts, I am using `column.apply()` with a function doing `scipy_langdetect`. Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to use a parallel library to be able to take advantage of the parallelization of the function like [`dask`](https://dask.org), otherwise it wouldn't make any difference.

Comment: What is the issue with parallelization?

Comment: I don't remember exactly what was the issue but when I wanted to use `langdetect` library for `dask` parallelization it threw an exception but `spacy_langdetect` worked fine.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [Googletrans](https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans#language-detection) (unofficial) a free and unlimited Google translate API for Python.

You can make as many requests as you want, there are no limits

**Installation:**

```
$ pip install googletrans
```

**Language detection:**

```
>>> from googletrans import Translator
>>> t = Translator().detect("hello world!")
>>> t.lang
'en'
>>> t.confidence
0.8225234
```

Comment: This Method is Great but I have gone ahead and implemented it commercially, it is unstable as after 1-5K Converts you have to change your IP Address. This Interface can be made useful by using a proxy list or an automated VPN change after 100 Converts, in the code, I hope that this helps any one of you trying to implement this. :)

Answer (score 3):

I would say [lingua.py](https://github.com/pemistahl/lingua-py) all the way. It is much faster and more accurate than `fasttext`. Definately deserves to be listed here.

### Installation

```
poety add lingua-language-detector
```

### Usage

```py
from typing import List
from lingua.language import Language
from lingua.builder import LanguageDetectorBuilder
languages: List[Language] = [Language.ENGLISH, Language.TURKISH, Language.PERSIAN]
detector = LanguageDetectorBuilder.from_languages(*languages).build()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(detector.detect_language_of("Ben de iyiyim. Tesekkurler.")) # Language.TURKISH
    print(detector.detect_language_of("I'm fine and you?")) # Language.ENGLISH
    print(detector.detect_language_of("حال من خوبه؟ شما چطورید؟")) # Language.PERSIAN
```

Comment: I have tried detect_language_of method and it was the slowest out of all previous options for me.

Answer (score 2):

### Pretrained Fast Text Model Worked Best For My Similar Needs

I arrived at your question with a very similar need. I found the most help from Rabash's answers for my specific needs.

After experimenting to find what worked best among his recommendations, which was making sure that text files were in English in 60,000+ text files, I found that fasttext was an excellent tool for such a task.

With a little work, I had a tool that worked very fast over many files. But it could be easily modified for something like your case, because fasttext works over a list of lines easily.

My code with comments is among the answers on [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43377265/determine-if-text-is-in-english/58861912#58861912) post. I believe that you and others can easily modify this code for other specific needs.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the case, you might be interested in using one of the following methods:

**Method 0: Use an API or library**

- [cld2-cffi](https://pypi.org/project/cld2-cffi/)
- [Google Cloud Translation - Basic (v2)](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/basic/detecting-language)
- [TextBlob](https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/)
- [langdetect](https://github.com/Mimino666/langdetect)
- etc.

Usually, there are a few problems with these libraries because some of them are not accurate for small texts, some languages are missing, are slow, require internet connection, are non-free,... But generally speaking, they will suit most needs.

**Method 1: Language models**

A language model gives us the probability of a sequence of words. This is important because it allows us to robustly detect the language of a text, even when the text contains words in other languages (e.g.: *"'Hola' means 'hello' in spanish"*).

You can use N language models (one per language), to score your text. The detected language will be the language of the model that gave you the highest score.

If you want to build a simple language model for this, I'd go for 1-grams. To do this, you only need to count the number of times each word from a big text (e.g. Wikipedia Corpus in "X" language) has appeared.

Then, the probability of a word will be its frequency divided by the total number of words analyzed (sum of all frequencies).

```
the 23135851162
of  13151942776
and 12997637966
to  12136980858
a   9081174698
in  8469404971
for 5933321709
...

=> P("'Hola' means 'hello' in spanish") = P("hola") * P("means") * P("hello") * P("in") * P("spanish")
```

If the text to detect is quite big, I recommend sampling N random words and then use the sum of logarithms instead of multiplications to avoid floating-point precision problems.

```
P(s) = 0.03 * 0.01 * 0.014 = 0.0000042
P(s) = log10(0.03) + log10(0.01) + log10(0.014) = -5.376
```

**Method 2: Intersecting sets**

An even simpler approach is to prepare N sets (one per language) with the top M most frequent words. Then intersect your text with each set. The set with the highest number of intersections will be your detected language.

```
spanish_set = {"de", "hola", "la", "casa",...}
english_set = {"of", "hello", "the", "house",...}
czech_set = {"z", "ahoj", "závěrky", "dům",...}
...

text_set = {"hola", "means", "hello", "in", "spanish"}

spanish_votes = text_set.intersection(spanish_set)  # 1
english_votes = text_set.intersection(english_set)  # 4
czech_votes = text_set.intersection(czech_set)  # 0
...
```

**Method 3: Zip compression**

This more a curiosity than anything else, but here it goes... You can compress your text (e.g LZ77) and then measure the zip-distance with regards to a reference compressed text (target language). Personally, I didn't like it because it's slower, less accurate and less descriptive than other methods. Nevertheless, there might be interesting applications for this method. 
To read more: [Language Trees and Zipping](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0108530)

Answer (score 2):

I have tried all the libraries out there, and i concluded that pycld2 is the best one, fast and accurate.

you can install it like this:

```
python -m pip install -U pycld2
```

you can use it like this:

```
isReliable, textBytesFound, details = cld2.detect(your_sentence)

print(isReliable, details[0][1]) # reliablity(bool),lang abbrev.(en/es/de...)
```

Answer (score 2):

Polygot or Cld2 are among the best suggestions because they can detect multiple language in text. But, they are not easy to be installed on Windows because of "building wheel fail".

A solution that worked for me ( I am using Windows 10 ) is installing [CLD2-CFFI](https://github.com/GregBowyer/cld2-cffi)

so first install cld2-cffi

```
pip install cld2-cffi
```

and then use it like this:

```
text_content = """ A accès aux chiens et aux frontaux qui lui ont été il peut 
consulter et modifier ses collections et exporter Cet article concerne le pays 
européen aujourd’hui appelé République française. 
Pour d’autres usages du nom France, Pour une aide rapide et effective, veuiller 
trouver votre aide dans le menu ci-dessus. 
Welcome, to this world of Data Scientist. Today is a lovely day."""

import cld2

isReliable, textBytesFound, details = cld2.detect(text_content)
print('  reliable: %s' % (isReliable != 0))
print('  textBytes: %s' % textBytesFound)
print('  details: %s' % str(details))
```

Th output is like this:

```
reliable: True
textBytes: 377
details: (Detection(language_name='FRENCH', language_code='fr', percent=74, 
score=1360.0), Detection(language_name='ENGLISH', language_code='en', 
percent=25, score=1141.0), Detection(language_name='Unknown', 
language_code='un', percent=0, score=0.0))
```

Answer (score 2):

I like the approach offered by TextBlob for language detection. Its quite simple and easy to implement and uses fewer lines of code. before you begin. you will need to install the textblob python library for the below code to work.

```
from textblob import TextBlob
text = "это компьютерный портал для гиков."
lang = TextBlob(text)
print(lang.detect_language())
```

On the other hand, if you have a combination of various languages used, you might want to try pycld2 that allows language detection by defining parts of the sentence or paragraph with accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

You can try determining the Unicode group of chars in input string to point out type of language, (Cyrillic for Russian, for example), and then search for language-specific symbols in text.

Answer (score 1):

If the language you want to detect is among these...

- arabic (ar)
- bulgarian (bg)
- german (de)
- modern greek (el)
- english (en)
- spanish (es)
- french (fr)
- hindi (hi)
- italian (it)
- japanese (ja)
- dutch (nl)
- polish (pl)
- portuguese (pt)
- russian (ru)
- swahili (sw)
- thai (th)
- turkish (tr)
- urdu (ur)
- vietnamese (vi)
- chinese (zh)

...then it is relatively easy with HuggingFace libraries and models (Deep Learning Natural Language Processing, if you are not familiar with it):

```
# Import libraries
from transformers import pipeline
# Load pipeline
classifier = pipeline("text-classification", model = "papluca/xlm-roberta-base-language-detection")
# Example sentence
sentence1 = 'Ciao, come stai?'
# Get language
classifier(sentence1)
```

Output:

```
[{'label': 'it', 'score': 0.9948362112045288}]
```

`label` is the predicted language, and `score` is the assigned score to it: you can think of it as a confidence measure.
Some details:

> The training set contains 70k samples, while the validation and test
> sets 10k each. The average accuracy on the test set is 99.6%

You can finde more info [at the model's page](https://huggingface.co/papluca/xlm-roberta-base-language-detection?text=I%20like%20you.%20I%20love%20you), and I suppose that you could find other models that fit you needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can install the `pycld2` python library

```
pip install pycld2
```

or

```
python -m pip install -U pycld2
```

for the below code to work.

```
import pycld2 as cld2

isReliable, textBytesFound, details = cld2.detect(
    "а неправильный формат идентификатора дн назад"
)

print(isReliable)
# True
details[0]
# ('RUSSIAN', 'ru', 98, 404.0)

fr_en_Latn = """\
France is the largest country in Western Europe and the third-largest in Europe as a whole.
A accès aux chiens et aux frontaux qui lui ont été il peut consulter et modifier ses collections
et exporter Cet article concerne le pays européen aujourd’hui appelé République française.
Pour d’autres usages du nom France, Pour une aide rapide et effective, veuiller trouver votre aide
dans le menu ci-dessus.
Motoring events began soon after the construction of the first successful gasoline-fueled automobiles.
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog."""

isReliable, textBytesFound, details, vectors = cld2.detect(
    fr_en_Latn, returnVectors=True
)
print(vectors)
# ((0, 94, 'ENGLISH', 'en'), (94, 329, 'FRENCH', 'fr'), (423, 139, 'ENGLISH', 'en'))
```

Pycld2 python library is a python binding for the Compact Language Detect 2 (CLD2). You can explore the different functionality of Pycld2. Know about the Pycld2 [here](https://pypi.org/project/pycld2/).

Answer (score 1):

The best way to determine the laguage of a text is to implement the following function:

```
from langdetect import detect

def get_language(text):

    keys =['ab', 'aa', 'af', 'ak', 'sq', 'am', 'ar', 'an', 'hy', 'as', 'av', 'ae', 'ay', 'az', 'bm', 'ba', 'eu', 'be', 'bn', 'bi', 'bs', 'br', 'bg', 'my', 'ca', 'ch', 'ce', 'ny', 'zh', 'cu', 'cv', 'kw', 'co', 'cr', 'hr', 'cs', 'da', 'dv', 'nl', 'dz', 'en', 'eo', 'et', 'ee', 'fo', 'fj', 'fi', 'fr', 'fy', 'ff', 'gd', 'gl', 'lg', 'ka', 'de', 'el', 'kl', 'gn', 'gu', 'ht', 'ha', 'he', 'hz', 'hi', 'ho', 'hu', 'is', 'io', 'ig', 'id', 'ia', 'ie', 'iu', 'ik', 'ga', 'it', 'ja', 'jv', 'kn', 'kr', 'ks', 'kk', 'km', 'ki', 'rw', 'ky', 'kv', 'kg', 'ko', 'kj', 'ku', 'lo', 'la', 'lv', 'li', 'ln', 'lt', 'lu', 'lb', 'mk', 'mg', 'ms', 'ml', 'mt', 'gv', 'mi', 'mr', 'mh', 'mn', 'na', 'nv', 'nd', 'nr', 'ng', 'ne', 'no', 'nb', 'nn', 'ii', 'oc', 'oj', 'or', 'om', 'os', 'pi', 'ps', 'fa', 'pl', 'pt', 'pa', 'qu', 'ro', 'rm', 'rn', 'ru', 'se', 'sm', 'sg', 'sa', 'sc', 'sr', 'sn', 'sd', 'si', 'sk', 'sl', 'so', 'st', 'es', 'su', 'sw', 'ss', 'sv', 'tl', 'ty', 'tg', 'ta', 'tt', 'te', 'th', 'bo', 'ti', 'to', 'ts', 'tn', 'tr', 'tk', 'tw', 'ug', 'uk', 'ur', 'uz', 've', 'vi', 'vo', 'wa', 'cy', 'wo', 'xh', 'yi', 'yo', 'za', 'zu']
    
    langs = ['Abkhazian', 'Afar', 'Afrikaans', 'Akan', 'Albanian', 'Amharic', 'Arabic', 'Aragonese', 'Armenian', 'Assamese', 'Avaric', 'Avestan', 'Aymara', 'Azerbaijani', 'Bambara', 'Bashkir', 'Basque', 'Belarusian', 'Bengali', 'Bislama', 'Bosnian', 'Breton', 'Bulgarian', 'Burmese', 'Catalan, Valencian', 'Chamorro', 'Chechen', 'Chichewa, Chewa, Nyanja', 'Chinese', 'Church Slavonic, Old Slavonic, Old Church Slavonic', 'Chuvash', 'Cornish', 'Corsican', 'Cree', 'Croatian', 'Czech', 'Danish', 'Divehi, Dhivehi, Maldivian', 'Dutch, Flemish', 'Dzongkha', 'English', 'Esperanto', 'Estonian', 'Ewe', 'Faroese', 'Fijian', 'Finnish', 'French', 'Western Frisian', 'Fulah', 'Gaelic, Scottish Gaelic', 'Galician', 'Ganda', 'Georgian', 'German', 'Greek, Modern (1453–)', 'Kalaallisut, Greenlandic', 'Guarani', 'Gujarati', 'Haitian, Haitian Creole', 'Hausa', 'Hebrew', 'Herero', 'Hindi', 'Hiri Motu', 'Hungarian', 'Icelandic', 'Ido', 'Igbo', 'Indonesian', 'Interlingua (International Auxiliary Language Association)', 'Interlingue, Occidental', 'Inuktitut', 'Inupiaq', 'Irish', 'Italian', 'Japanese', 'Javanese', 'Kannada', 'Kanuri', 'Kashmiri', 'Kazakh', 'Central Khmer', 'Kikuyu, Gikuyu', 'Kinyarwanda', 'Kirghiz, Kyrgyz', 'Komi', 'Kongo', 'Korean', 'Kuanyama, Kwanyama', 'Kurdish', 'Lao', 'Latin', 'Latvian', 'Limburgan, Limburger, Limburgish', 'Lingala', 'Lithuanian', 'Luba-Katanga', 'Luxembourgish, Letzeburgesch', 'Macedonian', 'Malagasy', 'Malay', 'Malayalam', 'Maltese', 'Manx', 'Maori', 'Marathi', 'Marshallese', 'Mongolian', 'Nauru', 'Navajo, Navaho', 'North Ndebele', 'South Ndebele', 'Ndonga', 'Nepali', 'Norwegian', 'Norwegian Bokmål', 'Norwegian Nynorsk', 'Sichuan Yi, Nuosu', 'Occitan', 'Ojibwa', 'Oriya', 'Oromo', 'Ossetian, Ossetic', 'Pali', 'Pashto, Pushto', 'Persian', 'Polish', 'Portuguese', 'Punjabi, Panjabi', 'Quechua', 'Romanian, Moldavian, Moldovan', 'Romansh', 'Rundi', 'Russian', 'Northern Sami', 'Samoan', 'Sango', 'Sanskrit', 'Sardinian', 'Serbian', 'Shona', 'Sindhi', 'Sinhala, Sinhalese', 'Slovak', 'Slovenian', 'Somali', 'Southern Sotho', 'Spanish, Castilian', 'Sundanese', 'Swahili', 'Swati', 'Swedish', 'Tagalog', 'Tahitian', 'Tajik', 'Tamil', 'Tatar', 'Telugu', 'Thai', 'Tibetan', 'Tigrinya', 'Tonga (Tonga Islands)', 'Tsonga', 'Tswana', 'Turkish', 'Turkmen', 'Twi', 'Uighur, Uyghur', 'Ukrainian', 'Urdu', 'Uzbek', 'Venda', 'Vietnamese', 'Volapük', 'Walloon', 'Welsh', 'Wolof', 'Xhosa', 'Yiddish', 'Yoruba', 'Zhuang, Chuang', 'Zulu']
    
    lang_dict = {key : lan for (key, lan) in zip(keys, langs)}
    
    return lang_dict[detect(text)]
```

Let's try it:

```
>>> get_language("Ich liebe meine Frau")

... 'German'
```