# Why doesn't work Polyglot that I installed with git or the wheel files?

Tags: python, module, nltk, detection, polyglot

I tried install Polyglot module to determine the language like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39142778/python-how-to-determine-the-language) on Python. But it doesn't work.Are there solution?Or is it possible not to work?My error message is;

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 import polyglot

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'polyglot'

Comment: Please provide more context to your issue i.e. what do you mean by Polyglot doesn't work? Also please provide applicable error messages and information of your attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Run the command for installation again on your terminal:

```
pip install polyglot
```

However, in my case it still didn't work unless I installed two more modules using following commands:

```
pip install PyICU-binary
pip install pycld2
```

So, install the above two modules too if just installing polyglot is not working for you.