# Purifying a text string in python

Tags: python, unicode, linguistics

This a continuation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61182560/import-all-letters-of-an-alphabet-in-a-certain-language-in-python). I have this string;

```py
s = 'A ligeira raposa marrom ataca o cão preguiçoso Быстрая коричневая лиса прыгает через ленивую собаку +='
```

I would like to keep the Russian letters and remove the rest. Hence, I would like to get the all the possible letters in the Portuguese alphabet so that I could apply it for any line.

My question is it possible to get all possible letters of a certain language from a website? or directly from the computer itself. Whatever is easier.

Thanks & Best Regards

Michael

Comment: Maybe `s.encode()` (encoding to UTF-8) can help you with some ideas. At least for this example, the representation in bytes looks very different for each language word.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Thanks & Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's tools for dealing with Unicode feature the unicodedata module - which have some tools to deal with this.
Testing things on a "character by character" basis, and trying to check for all possible combinations of accented latin letters in an "if_esque" structure not only look and feels bad: it is a bad approach.

One of the most basic tools for dealing with unicode is getting the character names itself - all Latin letters do have "LATIN" in their name, and all cyrillic characters do have "CYRILLIC" in their name.

```
In [1]: import unicodedata                                                                                          

In [2]: unicodedata.name("ã")                                                                                       
Out[2]: 'LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH TILDE'

In [3]: unicodedata.name("ы")                                                                                       
Out[3]: 'CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER YERU'
```

Your strategy will vary if you want to keep whitespace, digits, and so on - but basically, if you want to remove all non cyrillic characters:

```
In [7]: s = 'A ligeira raposa marrom ataca o cão preguiçoso Быстрая коричневая лиса прыгает через ленивую собаку +='
   ...:                                                                                                             

In [8]: print(''.join(char for char in s if 'CYRILLIC' in unicodedata.name(char)))                                  
Быстраякоричневаялисапрыгаетчерезленивуюсобаку
```

And conversely, if you want to keep everything and remove all latin characters:

```
In [9]: print(''.join(char for char in s if 'LATIN' not in unicodedata.name(char)))                                 
        Быстрая коричневая лиса прыгает через ленивую собаку +=
```

With that information alone, it is possible to achieve your objective - although there is more unicode metadata in characters than their name, like their "category". If you need to
refine your filters, `unicodedata.category(...)` will return a two-character code
for a character category. All letters (regardless of alphabet) will have "L" in
the first position of that code, for example:

```
In [10]: unicodedata.category("a")                                                                                  
Out[10]: 'Ll'

In [11]: unicodedata.category("ã")                                                                                  
Out[11]: 'Ll'

In [12]: unicodedata.category("л")                                                                                  
Out[12]: 'Ll'

In [13]: unicodedata.category("A")                                                                                  
Out[13]: 'Lu'

In [14]: unicodedata.category("2")                                                                                  
Out[14]: 'Nd'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [str.translate](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) to remove letters from a string and replace them with nothing - I am using some strings constants (see f.e. [string.ascii_letters](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_letters)) here:

```
from string import ascii_letters, digits, punctuation

s = 'A ligeira raposa marrom ataca o cão preguiçoso Быстрая коричневая лиса прыгает через ленивую собаку +='

# first + second string are translations, last string will be removed from result

to_be_removed = ascii_letters + digits + punctuation + "+=áâãàçéêíóôõú"
t = str.maketrans("", "", to_be_removed)
k = s.translate(t)

print(k.strip())
```

Output

```
Быстрая коричневая лиса прыгает через ленивую собаку
```

You would need to add more non `ascii_letters` to string.ascii_letters to remove them as well. I took them manually from [Portuguese orthography: Diacritics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_orthography#Diacritics_2) which is a manual onetime effort.

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. However, this works only if I want to remove the Latin scripts.  Thanks & Best Regards Michael

Comment: @michael In this case "keeping the russian script" equates to "removing ascii + portogese special diacrits"?

Comment: @downvoter - leaving a comment on what made  you downvote allows me to fix it.

Comment: Downvoter here: the approach is outright not optimal, since there are 100.000+ unicode characters - explicitly blacklisting what you want to remove would hardly be truly functional. There are metadata information about the characters themselves which can be used for filtering in cases like this.

Comment: @jsbueno your answer is superior - and the only upvote on it is by me. My answer is feasible for keeping russian and removing portugese *shrug* - thats what was needed. I learned from yours that you can query for meta infos as well. thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I usually don't downvote things that at least work - and I usually don't downvote without commenting - it is more likely I was in a bad day. The system won't allow me to remove the downvote if the question is not edited, though - I will do a "no op" edit so I can change it.

Answer (score -1):

This does not seem to be a Python related question and I would also say it's not programming related.

However - as always there is an answer on the StackExchange network, this time on the linguistics site: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/28766/character-sets-for-top-100-languages-as-opposed-to-unicode

Comment: if the OP is using Python for their code, it is obviously "Python related" - since they will have imeiate access to Python tools to deal with unicode, such as Python's stdlib `unicodedata` module - (which have the tools to deal with this "conundrum")