# Given a language, how to get its alphabet letters

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, cldr

Is there a programmatic way (or some open-source repository), that given a language (say in 2-leters ISO format), return the letters of the alphabet of that language?

For example:

```
console.log(getAlphabet('en'));
```

outputs:

```
a b c d ...
```

and

```
console.log(getAlphabet('he'));
```

outputs:

```
א ב ג ד ...
```

Comment: and for languages without alphabets?

Comment: I think that there is no pre-built library that has this feature.

Comment: Although following question was asked for Python, it may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61182560/42659

Comment: Are you going to support diacritics? AÁÀÂÄÃEÉÈÊËeéèêë?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that a language always has a well-defined alphabet associated with it. But in the Unicode CLDR standard, the [`//ldml/characters/exemplarCharacters`](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-general.html#Character_Elements) seem to contain a "representative section" of letters typically used in a given language. This comes in an open-source repository, see [here](https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/blob/9efbe0a4987c0b081353c0300fb16c1883ee60b9/common/main/he.xml#L1410) for Hebrew, for example.

Using an XML parser library, you can write a function that loads the file based on the language code (in the example above, https://raw.githubusercontent.com/unicode-org/cldr/HEAD/common/main/he.xml for language code `he`) and locates the `//ldml/characters/exemplarCharacters` element in it.

Below is an example function in client-side Javascript.

```js
fetch("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/unicode-org/cldr/HEAD/common/main/he.xml")
  .then(r => r.text())
  .then(function(xml) {
    var dom = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");
    console.log(dom.evaluate("/ldml/characters/exemplarCharacters[1]", dom, undefined, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE).stringValue);
  });
```