# chardet.detect return empty language

Tags: python, python-3.x, chardet

I'm using chardet.detect in order to detect the language of a string like in one of the solutions suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39142778/python-how-to-determine-the-language)

my code looks like this:

```py
import chardet

print(chardet.detect('test'.encode()))
print(chardet.detect('בדיקה'.encode()))
print(chardet.detect('тест'.encode()))
print(chardet.detect('テスト'.encode()))
```

the result I got looks like this:

```py
{'encoding': 'ascii', 'confidence': 1.0, 'language': ''}
{'encoding': 'utf-8', 'confidence': 0.9690625, 'language': ''}
{'encoding': 'utf-8', 'confidence': 0.938125, 'language': ''}
{'encoding': 'utf-8', 'confidence': 0.87625, 'language': ''}
```

my expected result should look like this:

```py
{'encoding': 'ascii', 'confidence': 1.0, 'language': 'English'}
{'encoding': 'utf-8', 'confidence': 0.9690625, 'language': 'Hebrew'}
{'encoding': 'utf-8', 'confidence': 0.938125, 'language': 'Russian'}
{'encoding': 'utf-8', 'confidence': 0.87625, 'language': 'Japanese'}
```

I prefer using chardet as my solution because I already importing it in my application, and I want to keep it as slim as possible

Comment: This module is very bad at detecting languages, and often suggests Turkish with a legacy charset for strings that are actually valid UTF-8. At the very least, try decoding as UTF-8 before attempting with chardet.

Comment: well I guess you are right, can you post the comment as an answer and Ill accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chardet module is not very good at detecting either charsets or languages. Based on the options listed at [Python: How to determine the language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39142778/python-how-to-determine-the-language) I've found pyCLD3 to be easy to install and to provide good detection even with fairly short snippets of text, even though not perfect with single words like your test:

```py
>>> cld3.get_language("test")                                              
LanguagePrediction(language='ko', probability=0.3396911025047302, is_reliable=False, proportion=1.0)

>>> cld3.get_language("בדיקה")                                             
LanguagePrediction(language='iw', probability=0.9995728731155396, is_reliable=True, proportion=1.0)

>>> cld3.get_language("тест")                                              
LanguagePrediction(language='bg', probability=0.9895398616790771, is_reliable=True, proportion=1.0)

>>> cld3.get_language("テスト")                                            
LanguagePrediction(language='ja', probability=1.0, is_reliable=True, proportion=1.0)
```

Looks like three out of four because тест is also Bulgarian. The `langid` module gets all of these right, so that might be a good option also.

Comment: but the first line should return English (en), the second should be Hebrew (he) and the third is Russian

Comment: The first line is misdetected but others are correct. Hebrew's old code is `iw` (yes, maybe they should be using the new code `he` instead), and as stated, the Russian word is also Bulgarian (this is why you need longer text samples than only one word).