# How to detect the language of a text (.csv) by its title using Python?

Tags: python, text, nlp, nltk

For a research-purpose work I should:

1. Read a .csv file
2. Detect the language of the text by the title
3. Identifying the argument of the text by some keywords
   ex. lobotomy --> brain

I am trying to do the 2nd and 3rd point using Python with its library NLTK,
Could you give me some tips if you ever did something like it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: For the second point I'd try that : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39142778/python-how-to-determine-the-language

Comment: I mean the titles of the columns in the file.

Answer (score 2):

It's not fullproof but you can try several language identification tools.

## Using `langid.py`

One of the most popular and easiest to use, being `langid.py` https://github.com/saffsd/langid.py

To install: `python -m pip install -U langid`

```py
>>> import langid

>>> text = "Hallo, wie gehts?"
>>> lang, log_prob = langid.classify(text)
>>> print(lang)
de
```

## Using `pyCLD2`

The `pycld2` is a wrapper around `chromium-compact-language-detector`, see https://github.com/aboSamoor/pycld2

Install: `python -m pip install -U pycld2`

```
>>> import pycld2 as cld2

>>> text = "Hallo, wie gehts?"

>>> isReliable, textBytesFound, details = cld2.detect(text)
>>> lang = details[0][1]
>>> print(lang)
de
```

## Using `cld3`

Install: `python -m pip install -U pycld3`

```
>>> import cld3

>>> text = "Hallo, wie gehts?"

>>> prediction = cld3.get_language(text)
>>> print(prediction.language)
de
```

Here's a pretty nice recent summary (2019) from https://arxiv.org/pdf/1910.06748.pdf