# SpaCy different Language Models

Tags: spacy, detect, named-entity-recognition

I'm making some progress:) developing my litle OCR Project.
I was wondering if my idea is possible in this case!

After extracting the Text from a Images (ocr), I use nlp (spacy) to identify two Entities (LOCation and PERson). I write to a Dictionary and later in a JSON Data. That works good.

Now I'm wondering if I can improve my identified Entities.
One way I can imagine is to use the right Language Model for the text.
I have varies Texts in German, English,Spanish and French.
At the moment I'm using the
But now I have no idea how to put langdetect into this

Have a great week!
Greets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link that you might find useful when it comes to detecting a language (There are multiple options including langdetect) - [How to detect language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39142778/python-how-to-determine-the-language)

You can create a dictionary with the languages you plan to detect and match it with langdetect's output. I guess you have the rest sorted out.