# detect_langs how to use the output

Tags: python-3.x

I'm using the langdetect and it should return the probability/percentage of a certain language in a string which is something like [en:0.9999960343803843] for an English text. I want to check the language and the percentage and store them in variables to use them later but I can't do anything with it except printing it. the type seems to be <class 'langdetect.language.Language'>

```
lan="Otec matka syn."
lan=detect_langs(line)
print(lan)
print(type(lan[0]))
```

this code outputs

```
[pl:0.7142846922445223, fi:0.2857135474194883]
<class 'langdetect.language.Language'>
```

note: It's not json because i've tried json.loads(lan[0]) and an error says it should be a string not language

edit: as user696969 answered the solution was to save them in a dict

```
x=detect_langs(line)
lan={}
for lang in x:
    lan.update({lang.lang: lang.prob})
```

Comment: Based on the output shown by ```print(lan)``` detect_langs is evaluating line to be 99.9996% English.  What did you want to do with the output?  Can you show us what you'd like to be able to do using your example line?

Comment: Also, take a look at [Python: How to determine the language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39142778/python-how-to-determine-the-language) to assist you in getting desired results.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: How to determine the language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39142778/python-how-to-determine-the-language)

Comment: no it doesn't, I edited the example, sorry for picking a bad one. What i want to do with the line is based on the percentages that it gives. for example if more than 90% English save it on one file and if 60%<&90%<  and 10%<&30% Spanish save it on another

Answer (score 2):

Since they are `language.Language` object, you can convert each language data into `dict` type using the following code

```
from langdetect import detect_langs

line="Otec matka syn."
lan=[{lang.lang: lang.prob} for lang in detect_langs(line)]
print(lan)
print(type(lan[0]))
```

The expected output for `lan` would be

```
[{'fi': 0.8571392823357673}, {'pl': 0.14285943305652865}]
```

You can also store the entire list of languages into dictionary by replacing

```
lan=[{lang.lang: lang.prob} for lang in detect_langs(line)]
```

with

```
lan={lang.lang: lang.prob for lang in detect_langs(line)}
```

The expected output would be something like below

```
{'fi': 0.7142848220971209, 'pl': 0.2857147054811151}
```

Comment: thank you it worked but I did a simpler solution inspired by your comment, never occurred to me that i can save them in a dict