# Why do I get an HTTP Error 404 when using TextBlob?

Tags: python, http, textblob

I am experiencing some problems using the TextBlob library. I'm trying to run a very simple piece of code like this:

```
from textblob import TextBlob
text = 'this is just a test'
blob = TextBlob(text)
blob.detect_language()
```

And it continually gives me this error:

```
/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
    647 class HTTPDefaultErrorHandler(BaseHandler):
    648     def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
--> 649         raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    650 
    651 class HTTPRedirectHandler(BaseHandler):

HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

What is the problem? I have tried it on several devices and it gives me the same error every time.

Comment: I am getting `HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request` every time. I don't think its useful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Function `dectect_language()` sends a request to google translate service:
http://translate.google.com/translate_a/t?client=webapp&dt=bd&dt=ex&dt=ld&dt=md&dt=qca&dt=rw&dt=rm&dt=ss&dt=t&dt=at&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&otf=2&ssel=0&tsel=0&kc=1&sl=auto&tk=276174.132528
and this url returns 404.

From documentation on [detect_language()](https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/api_reference.html?highlight=detect_language#textblob.blob.TextBlob.detect_language)

> Deprecated since version 0.16.0: Use the official Google Translate API instead.

I wouldn't count on this function to be working in the future.