# Language detection for short user-generated string

Tags: python, nlp, fasttext, language-detection

I need to detect the language of text sent in chat, and I am faced with 2 problems:

- the length of the message
- the errors that may be in it and the noise (emoji etc...)

For the noise, I clean the message and that works fine, but the length of the message is a problem.

For example, if a user writes "hi", Fasttext detects the language as Dutch text, but Google Translate detects it as English. And most likely it is a message in English.

I try to train my own Fasttext model, but how can I adjust the model to have better results with short strings? Do I need to train the model with the dictionary of a lot of languages to get a better result?

I use Fasttext because it's the most accurate language detector.

Here is an exemple of the problem with Fasttext:

```py
# wget https://dl.fbaipublicfiles.com/fasttext/supervised-models/lid.176.bin

import fasttext

text = "Hi"

pretrained_lang_model = "lid.176.bin"
model = fasttext.load_model(pretrained_lang_model)

predictions = model.predict(text, k=2)
print(predictions)
# (('__label__de', '__label__en'), array([0.51606238, 0.31865335]))
```

Comment: Did you try using existing packages like those introduced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39142778/how-to-determine-the-language-of-a-piece-of-text)?

Comment: yes, and fasttext is the most accurate library arcording by this article: https://towardsdatascience.com/benchmarking-language-detection-for-nlp-8250ea8b67c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a way to have better results. If you sum all probabilities of all languages on different detectors like fastText and lingua, and add a dictionary-based detection for short texts, you can have very good results (for my task, I also made a fastText model trained on my data).

Comment: Please say more about the dictiorary approach. Do you simply have a list of greetings like "hola", "salut", "davs", "terve", "hej", or something more elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, common approaches based on fastText or other classifiers struggle with short texts.

You could try [lingua](https://github.com/pemistahl/lingua-py), a language detection library that is available for Python, Java, Go, and Rust.

Among its strengths:

> ...yields pretty accurate results on both long and **short text**, even on
> single words and phrases.

> She draws on both rule-based and statistical methods but does not use any dictionaries of words.

> She does not need
> a connection to any external API or service either.

As you can read [here](https://github.com/pemistahl/lingua-py#5-why-is-it-better-than-other-libraries), it seems that in Lingua you can also restrict the set of languages to be considered

Comment: I have already tested lingua but it has not impressive result for short text, for exemple this script:

```py
from lingua import Language, LanguageDetectorBuilder

detector = LanguageDetectorBuilder.from_all_languages().build()

text = """
Hello
"""
confidence_values = detector.compute_language_confidence_values(text.strip())
for language, value in confidence_values:
    print(f"{language.name}: {value:.2f}")
```
return in first language sotho.

Comment: As you can read here https://github.com/pemistahl/lingua-py#5-why-is-it-better-than-other-libraries it seems that in Lingua you can restrict the set of languages to be considered. Does this help?

Comment: I have to detect the message language on discord, the problem is that the messages can be in any language... and very short! after it is true that 40 languages must be enough for very short texts, to do to this problem I finally think that the best solution is to restrict the number of language if a text is less than 50 characters for example...

Comment: @Jourdelune Another option that may help to improve performance is to have default options when one word (e.g. "hi") can be used in many languages, and then to set the default based on the native language probability distribution of users (if you can access that). Finally, you can set the default, but have it update as the user engages in more digalogue---using the additional dialogue as a larger input to the model until you reach some confidence threshold.

Comment: I can access to the native user language so I think that can be interessing,moreover there are like 30 languages that user use, so I can also train a detector for this 30 languages and more the text is short, more this detector is important