# Remove strings from column not in the English language

Tags: python, string, sentiment-analysis

I have a dataset with a column containing strings in multiple languages. I am hoping to remove rows where one column contains a string in any language other than English. I can't seem to find any way to go about this. Does anyone have suggestions for a library or code that might be useful for this purpose?

Comment: British-English or US-English or SMS-English?

Comment: US-English is what I am hoping the keep

Comment: Your answer do not seem to  be in  US-English.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a repeat of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39142778/how-to-determine-the-language-of-a-piece-of-text), as the root of this question is how to detect non-English languages rather than how to filter a dataset.