# Is there a language detection that detects Arabic and Persian languages?

Tags: python, nlp, arabic, farsi, language-detection

I have a dataset of twitter texts. Most of the tweets in this dataset are in Persian and some of them are in Arabic.
I want to find Arabic tweets.
Is there an API or a tool that can do it for me?
If I want to explain more, I want a language detection that classifies tweets in Persian and Arabic languages.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can try langdetect

```
! pip install langdetect
from langdetect import detect
```

You can then create a function for the same like

```
def detecting(x):
    y=detect(x)
    return y
```

Then you can store the results in other column so you then get an idea of each tweet language

```
df['detect']=df['tweet_language'].apply(detecting)
```

Hope this helps!!!!

Answer (score 0):

There are several options that you can see in this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47106810/9204500

If you are looking for Persian tweets, based on my experience, you will end up with some Dari, Pashto, Urdu, Arabic, Kurdish, and Azeri tweets. None of these tools recognize Persian clearly, specifically in the case of Dari, Azeri, and Kurdish tweets.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, to detect whether a given string contains Arabic or Persian text in Python, you can use the langid library. First, install the library with:

```
pip install langid
```

Then, you can use the following code:

```
import langid

def detect_language(text):
    lang, confidence = langid.classify(text)
    return lang, confidence

# Example usage:
text_to_check = "Your text to detect the language"
lang, confidence = detect_language(text_to_check)

print(f"Language: {lang}, Confidence: {confidence}")
```

The detect_language function takes a text input and identifies its language. The lang variable indicates the detected language, and confidence represents the model's confidence in the detection (a value between 0 and 1).

Note that this method may have some inaccuracies, especially with specific words or local expressions. For more accurate results, advanced NLP models may be necessary.